# How to find Parent Id in an Intended Hierarchy

Tags: excel

I have hierarchy Excel sheet data as shown below,[image]

I try to get parent Id in second column,a forum suggest me try this code

```
=IF(B2<>"",MATCH($A2,INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(B2,$A:$A,0)&":I"&MATCH(B2,$A:$A,0)),0),"Blank")
```

to get like this result,

[image]

In this case, I couldn't get result like this.

Anyone suggest me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a more generic formula if you need. It will work if the sequences are not exactly like 3 Ds in a column etc.

It is an array formula, which must be entered in B2 with

> **Ctrl-Shift-Enter**

and then copied down.

```
=IF(MAX(N($C2:$F2<>""))=0, "Blank", IF($C2<>"", 0, INDEX($A:$A, MAX(IF(INDEX($C$2:$F2, 0, MIN(IF(--($C2:$F2<>""), COLUMN($C2:$F2)-COLUMN($C:$C), 9E+99)))<>"", ROW($A$2:$A2), -9E+99)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
=IF(C2<>"",0,IF(D2<>"",A2-1,IF(E2<>"",A2-1,IF(AND(F2<>"",LEFT(F2,1)=LEFT(F1,1)),B1,A2-1))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for help. if i try, D1,D2,D3 parent id are 3,4,5. But your screent shot is so nice. whats wrong ?

Comment: so, Do i need 2 formula for this issue?

Comment: The formula should work if you just copy it in cell B2 and drag down. If have shared a screenshot of what my formal would like in cell B6. Compare it and see if you have the same, otherwise you are not dragging the formula down correctly.

Comment: No, only one formula. This is just an example.

Comment: My B6 formula is: =IF(C6<>"",0,IF(D6<>"",A6-1,IF(E6<>"",A6-1,IF(AND(F6<>"",F6=F5),B5,A6-1))))

Comment: Sorry, my formula was not complete. try now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130051/discussion-between-venkat-and-vba-pete).